# Spark ETL job execute mysql only once

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I have an ETL job in Spark that also connects to MySQL in order to grab some data. Historically, I've been doing it as follows:

```
hiveContext.read().jdbc(
   dbProperties.getProperty("myDbInfo"),
   "(SELECT id, name FROM users) r",
   new Properties()).registerTempTable("tmp_users");

Row[] res = hiveContext.sql("SELECT "
    + "   u.name, "
    + "   SUM(s.revenue) AS revenue "
    + "FROM "
    + "   stats s "
    + "   INNER JOIN tmp_users u "
    + "       ON u.id = s.user_id
    + "GROUP BY "
    + "   u.name "
    + "ORDER BY "
    + "   revenue DESC 
    + "LIMIT 10").collect();

String ids = "";
// now grab me some info for users that are in tmp_user_stats
for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    s += (!s.equals("") ? "," : "") + res[i](0);
}

hiveContext.jdbc(
dbProperties.getProperty("myDbInfo"),
"(SELECT name, surname, home_address FROM users WHERE id IN ("+ids+")) r",
new Properties()).registerTempTable("tmp_users_prises");
```

However, when scaling this to multiple worker nodes, whenever I use the `tmp_users` table, it runs the query and it gets executed (at least) once per node, which boils down to our db admin running around offices with a knife.

What's the best way to handle this? Can I run the job on like 3 machines, limiting it to 3 queries and then write the data to Hadoop for other nodes to use it or what?

Essentially - as suggested in comments - I could run a query outside of the ETL job which can prepare data from MySQL side and import it to Hadoop. However, there could be subsequent queries, which suggest a solution more *in line* with Spark and JDBC connection setup.

I'll accept the Sqoop solution as it at least give a more streamlined solution, although I'm still not yet sure it will do the job. If I find something, I'll edit the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache data:

```
val initialDF = hiveContext.read().jdbc(
   dbProperties.getProperty("myDbInfo"),
   "(SELECT id, name FROM users) r",
   new Properties())
initialDF.cache();
initialDF.registerTempTable("tmp_users");
```

After first read, data will be cached in memory

Alternative (that doesn't hurt DBA ;) ) is to use Sqoop with parameter `--num-mappers=3` and then import result file to Spark